# Weird Zeros are appended at the end of double values returned by Soap Web Service

Tags: php, web-services, soap

The WSDL file is located here : http://www.rasd.ro/BSEFinancialsWS/financials.asmx?WSDL
Here's the operation page: http://www.rasd.ro/BSEFinancialsWS/financials.asmx?op=GetCompanyBalance

For **IdentityType** try **Symbol**

For **Identity** try **BVB**

For **ReportType** try **Q1**

For **Year** try **2011**

Basically, what you`ll get is:

```
> <CompanyBalance> 
> <Company>
>    <CompanyName>SC BURSA DE VALORI BUCURESTI SA</CompanyName>
>    <FiscalCode>17777754</FiscalCode>
> </Company> 
> <LastYear>2011</LastYear>
> <ReportType>Q1</ReportType>
> <NetCrtLiab>64931998</NetCrtLiab>
> <CrtAssets>67220118</CrtAssets>
> <FixedAssets>25299375</FixedAssets>
> <PaidUpCap>76741980</PaidUpCap>
> <ShahEqy>90231373</ShahEqy>
> <OpExp>2975724</OpExp>
> <ExtrExp>0</ExtrExp>
> <FinExp>1411570</FinExp>
> <TotExp>4387294</TotExp>
> <NetTurn>5977651</NetTurn>
> <Debt1>0</Debt1>
> <Debt2>2086920</Debt2>
> <TotLiab>2086920</TotLiab>
> <BackPay>0</BackPay>
> <NoPaidTax>0</NoPaidTax>
> <Empl>57</Empl> <BackLiab>0</BackLiab>
> <BackPaym>0</BackPaym>
> <Gross>2624119</Gross>
> <OpRes>3002199</OpRes>
> <ExtrRes>0</ExtrRes>
> <FinRes>-378080</FinRes>
> <NetRes>2196413</NetRes>
> <CurrRes>2624119</CurrRes>
> <ResPerShare xsi:nil="true"/>
> <TotAssets>90231373</TotAssets>
> <TotReceiv>3368756</TotReceiv>
> <RevInAdv>584055</RevInAdv>
> <OpIncome>5977923</OpIncome>
> <ExIncome>0</ExIncome>
> <FinInc>1033490</FinInc>
> <TotRev>**7011413**</TotRev>
> </CompanyBalance>
```

Notice the **TotRev** value? Well, it`s exactly how it`s supposed to be.
Now, in my implementation of the SoapClient I have:

...

```
static $WSConf=array(
        'financials'=>array('host'=>'rasd.ro','port'=>80,'wsdlURL'=>'http://www.rasd.ro/BSEFinancialsWS/financials.asmx?WSDL'),
        'companies'=>array('host'=>'rasd.ro','port'=>80,'wsdlURL'=>'http://www.rasd.ro/BSEFinancialsWS/companiesandsecurities.asmx?WSDL'),);
```

...

```
private static function S($name) {

    $name=strtolower($name);

    if(!is_object(self::$soapClients[$name])) {
        self::$soapClients[$name] = new SoapClient(self::$WSConf[$name]['wsdlURL']);    
    }
    if(is_object(self::$soapClients[$name])) {

        self::Delay();

        return self::$soapClients[$name];
    }
    error_log('site.ro '.__FILE__.' error'."\n\n".__FILE__.': '.__CLASS___.'::'.__METHOD__."\n\n msc_WebServBVB2 ".date('Y-M-d H:i:s')."\nCannot init webservice {$name}", 3, WSBVBExtLOG);
}
```

...

```
public static function RaportareFinanciara($simbol,$timestampOrAn,$trimestru=false){
        self::timerReset();
        if(empty($trimestru)) {
            $trimestru=utilsDT::Quarter($timestampOrAn);
            $an=date('Y',$timestampOrAn);
        }else{
            $an=$timestampOrAn;
        }



        $IdentityType='Symbol';
        $Identity=$simbol;
        $Year=$an;
        $ReportType=strtr($trimestru,array('1'=>'Q1','2'=>'Semestrial','3'=>'Q3','4'=>'Annual'));

        $balanceType=self::GetBalanceType($IdentityType,$Identity,$ReportType,$Year);
        $type=$balanceType['BalanceType'];
        if(!empty($type)) {

            switch($type) {

                case 'Company':
                    $balance=self::GetCompanyBalance($IdentityType,$Identity,$ReportType,$Year);
                    break;

                case 'Bank':
                    $balance=self::GetBankBalance($IdentityType,$Identity,$ReportType,$Year);
                    break;

                case 'Assurance':
                    $balance=self::GetInsuranceBalance($IdentityType,$Identity,$ReportType,$Year);
                    break;

                case 'Fund':
                    $balance=self::GetInvestmentFundsBalance($IdentityType,$Identity,$ReportType,$Year);
                    break;

                default:
                    return false;
            }


            if(!empty($balance)) {

                if(self::$debug) {
                    self::timerAddAction("Mapping balance fields to compatibility names for ".strtolower($type));   
                }

                if(isset(self::$BVBROAPI_FldCorespCustom[strtolower($type)])) {
                    $FldCoresp=array_merge(self::$BVBROAPI_FldCoresp,self::$BVBROAPI_FldCorespCustom[strtolower($type)]);
                }else{
                    $FldCoresp=self::$BVBROAPI_FldCoresp;
                }

                if(self::$debug) {
                    print_r($FldCoresp);
                }

                $result=array();
                foreach($FldCoresp as $compat_name=>$wsname) {
                    if(isset($balance[$wsname])) {
                        $result[$compat_name]=$balance[$wsname];                        
                    }
                }

                $result['BallanceType']=$type;
                if(!empty($result)) {
                    if(self::$debug) {
                        self::timerPrintInfo();
                    }
                    return $result;
                }
            }
            if(self::$debug) {
                self::timerAddAction("Balance empty");  
            }

        }
        if(self::$debug) {
            self::timerPrintInfo();
        }
        return false;

    }
```

...

public static function GetCompanyBalance($IdentityType,$Identity,$ReportType,$Year){
        self::timerReset();

```
    if(self::$debug) {
        self::timerAddAction("Called GetCompanyBalance ($IdentityType,$Identity,$ReportType,$Year) Method");    
    }   

    $cacheid='webservbvbext_balance'.$IdentityType.$Identity.$ReportType.$Year;

    if(self::$debug) {
        self::timerAddAction("Checking cache");

    }
    if(self::CM()->cacheIsExpired($cacheid)) {


        if(self::$debug) {
            self::timerAddAction("Calling webservice Method");  
        }

        try{

            $rawresult=self::S('Financials')->GetCompanyBalance(array('IdentityType'=>$IdentityType,'Identity'=>$Identity,'ReportType'=>$ReportType,'Year'=>$Year));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if(self::$debug) {
                self::timerAddAction('Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage());  
            }
            return false;
        }



        if(self::$debug) {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($rawresult);
            echo '</pre>';  
        }

        if(self::$debug) {
            self::timerAddAction("Mapping array fields");
        }


        if(!empty($rawresult) && sizeof($rawresult)>=1) {
            $fields=array();
            foreach($rawresult->GetCompanyBalanceResult as $key=>$Field) {

                $Field=(is_object($Field) ? (array) $Field : $Field);
                $fields[$key]=$Field;

            }

            if($fields['LastYear']!=$Year || $fields['ReportType']!=$ReportType) {
                return false;
            }


            if(self::$debug) {
                self::timerAddAction("Caching results");

            }

            self::CM()->cacheThis($cacheid,'',self::$cacheTime['Ballance'],$fields,true);


            if(self::$debug) {
                self::timerAddAction("Finished caching. Return data");

            }
            if(self::$debug) {
                self::timerPrintInfo();
            }
            if(!empty($fields)) {
                return $fields;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }else{
        $out=self::CM()->getCached($cacheid);
        if(is_array($out) && !empty($out)) {
            if(self::$debug) {

                self::timerAddAction("Cached Request Details: ".date('Y.m.d H:i:s',self::CM()->cacheTimeStmp($cacheid)));
                self::timerPrintInfo();
            }

            return $out;
        }
        return false;


    }
```

...

So running something like this:

```
    $result=msc_WebServBVBExt::GetCompanyBalance('Symbol','BVB','Q1',2011);



echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Returns:

```
Array
```

(
    [Company] => Array
        (
            [CompanyName] => SC BURSA DE VALORI BUCURESTI SA
            [FiscalCode] => 17777754
        )

```
[LastYear] => 2011
[ReportType] => Q1
[NetCrtLiab] => 6493199800
[CrtAssets] => 6722011800
[FixedAssets] => 2529937500
[PaidUpCap] => 7674198000
[ShahEqy] => 9023137300
[OpExp] => 297572400
[ExtrExp] => 0
[FinExp] => 141157000
[TotExp] => 438729400
[NetTurn] => 597765100
[Debt1] => 0
[Debt2] => 208692000
[TotLiab] => 208692000
[BackPay] => 0
[NoPaidTax] => 0
[Empl] => 57
[BackLiab] => 0
[BackPaym] => 0
[Gross] => 262411900
[OpRes] => 300219900
[ExtrRes] => 0
[FinRes] => -37808000
[NetRes] => 219641300
[CurrRes] => 262411900
[ResPerShare] => 
[TotAssets] => 9023137300
[TotReceiv] => 336875600
[RevInAdv] => 58405500
[OpIncome] => 597792300
[ExIncome] => 0
[FinInc] => 103349000
**[TotRev] => 701141300**
```

)

```
}
```

As you notice from the last value, it has 2 zeros appended at the end of the value.
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps that value is supposed to be dollars and cents. Many financial systems are designed to store money in an integer format that represents the amount in cents or mils as oppose dollars.

Comment: That might be the issue, but the problem is, my script never get`s to store anything because the value is wrong. Just calling the web service get`s me 2 zeros appended to the value, so why would I store a wrong value. Instead running the web service from their operation point, http://www.rasd.ro/BSEFinancialsWS/financials.asmx?op=GetCompanyBalance, with the details mentioned above, returns the correct value, that is 7011413